# how can I SELECT English or Arabic when switch between languages after login?

Tags: oracle-apex

I want to use globalization in my application and use English application or Arabic application in oracle apex

I created new Dynamic menu list and I am using the following SQL QUERY :

```
SELECT LEVEL,
           MENU_NAME_ENGLISH
                      label,
                  'f?p=' || :APP_ID || ':' || MENU_LINK || ':' || :APP_SESSION
                      target,
                  'NO:'
                      is_current,
                  NVL (icon_img, 'fa-apex-square')
                      image,
                  PARENT_OID
             FROM MENUS
             WHERE OID IN (SELECT PAGE_ID
                           FROM USER_GROUP_PAGE_ACCESS
                           WHERE PID_GROUP = :P0_USER_GROUP)
       START WITH PARENT_OID IS NULL
       CONNECT BY PRIOR OID = PARENT_OID
ORDER SIBLINGS BY SORT_BY;
```

also in login page I created page item radio group for languages and give static
value for English value en-us and for Arabic ar-sa
then created a process to switch between languages this is the code used in process :

```
begin
apex_util.set_session_lang(:P9999_LANGUAGE);
end;
```

when I logged in to Arabic language its show English labels also because I SELECT

how can I make if statement in the dynamic menu query and SELECT Arabic names if login for Arabic language and select English names when login to English system

```
if apex_util.set_session_lang('ar-sa')
then 
   
SELECT LEVEL,
           MENU_NAME_ARABIC
                      label,
                  'f?p=' || :APP_ID || ':' || MENU_LINK || ':' || :APP_SESSION
                      target,
                  'NO:'
                      is_current,
                  NVL (icon_img, 'fa-apex-square')
                      image,
                  PARENT_OID
             FROM MENUS
             WHERE OID IN (SELECT PAGE_ID
                           FROM USER_GROUP_PAGE_ACCESS
                           WHERE PID_GROUP = :P0_USER_GROUP)
       START WITH PARENT_OID IS NULL
       CONNECT BY PRIOR OID = PARENT_OID
ORDER SIBLINGS BY SORT_BY;

else 
 
SELECT LEVEL,
           MENU_NAME_ENGLISH
                      label,
                  'f?p=' || :APP_ID || ':' || MENU_LINK || ':' || :APP_SESSION
                      target,
                  'NO:'
                      is_current,
                  NVL (icon_img, 'fa-apex-square')
                      image,
                  PARENT_OID
             FROM MENUS
             WHERE OID IN (SELECT PAGE_ID
                           FROM USER_GROUP_PAGE_ACCESS
                           WHERE PID_GROUP = :P0_USER_GROUP)
       START WITH PARENT_OID IS NULL
       CONNECT BY PRIOR OID = PARENT_OID
ORDER SIBLINGS BY SORT_BY;
```

the dynamic list use SQL QUERY or function return SQL QUERY ?

UPDATE :

this is MENUS table definition :

```
 CREATE TABLE "MENUS" 
   (    "OID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "PARENT_OID" NUMBER, 
    "MENU_NAME_ENGLISH" NVARCHAR2(100), 
    "MENU_LINK" NVARCHAR2(200), 
    "STATUS" NVARCHAR2(1), 
    "DESCRIPTION" NVARCHAR2(200), 
    "SORT_BY" NUMBER, 
    "PID_EMPLOYEE_INSERT_BY" NUMBER, 
    "PID_EMPLOYEE_UPDATE_BY" NUMBER, 
    "UPDATE_DATE" DATE, 
    "INSERT_DATE" DATE DEFAULT sysdate, 
    "ICON_IMG" VARCHAR2(250), 
    "MENU_NAME_ARABIC" VARCHAR2(250), 
     CONSTRAINT "MENUS_C01" CHECK (parent_oid <> oid) ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "MENUS_CON_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("OID")
  USING INDEX  ENABLE
   )  ENABLE ROW MOVEMENT ;

  ALTER TABLE "MENUS" ADD CONSTRAINT "MENUS_CON" FOREIGN KEY ("PARENT_OID")
      REFERENCES "MENUS" ("OID") ENABLE;
```

this is USER_GROUP_PAGE_ACCESS definition :

```
CREATE TABLE "USER_GROUP_PAGE_ACCESS" 
   (    "OID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "PID_GROUP" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "PAGE_ID" NUMBER, 
    "PERMISSION" NUMBER(1,0) DEFAULT 1, 
     CONSTRAINT "ACL_GROUP_PAGE_ACCESS_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("OID")
  USING INDEX  ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "ACL_GROUP_PAGE_ACCESS_U01" UNIQUE ("PID_GROUP", "PAGE_ID")
  USING INDEX  ENABLE
   )  ENABLE ROW MOVEMENT ;
```

this example of INSERT statement :

```
    INSERT INTO menus (
        oid,
        parent_oid,
        menu_name_english,
        menu_link,
        status,
        description,
        sort_by,
        pid_employee_insert_by,
        pid_employee_update_by,
        update_date,
        insert_date,
        icon_img,
        menu_name_arabic ) 
VALUES 
 (1,null,'Page1',1,1,'page1',null,null,null,null,null,null,'صفحة1');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd think you could use a case statement in your select to show arabic or english based on the session language.

```
SELECT LEVEL,
       CASE WHEN APEX_UTIL.GET_SESSION_LANG = 'ar-sa' 
              THEN MENU_NAME_ARABIC 
            ELSE MENU_NAME_ENGLISH
            END
                      label,
                  'f?p=' || :APP_ID || ':' || MENU_LINK || ':' || :APP_SESSION
                      target,
                  'NO:'
                      is_current,
                  NVL (icon_img, 'fa-apex-square')
                      image,
                  PARENT_OID
             FROM MENUS
             WHERE OID IN (SELECT PAGE_ID
                           FROM USER_GROUP_PAGE_ACCESS
                           WHERE PID_GROUP = :P0_USER_GROUP)
       START WITH PARENT_OID IS NULL
       CONNECT BY PRIOR OID = PARENT_OID
ORDER SIBLINGS BY SORT_BY;
```

--UPDATE--

From your table definition it is clear that the columns MENU_NAME_ARABIC and MENU_NAME_ENGLISH do not have the same datatype. That is the cause of the character set mismatch error. The solution is to cast one of the colums to the other datatype so both arguments in the case statement have the same datatype.

```
...

       CASE WHEN APEX_UTIL.GET_SESSION_LANG = 'ar-sa' 
              THEN MENU_NAME_ARABIC 
            ELSE CAST(MENU_NAME_ENGLISH AS VARCHAR2(200))
            END
...
```

However... I would take a step back and research if the datatype `NVARCHAR2` is really needed. For a database with a character set that supports multibyte characters (eg UTF8) there should be no need to ever use NVARCHAR2. All characters can be stored in VARCHAR2 data type columns.
In your table definition, the only column for which it makes sense to use NVARCHAR2 would be the MENU_NAME_ARABIC one, not MENU_NAME_ENGLISH, not sure why you picked that. If you have more questions about this I'd file a new question since I'm not a specialist in that matter.

Comment: I tried the SELECT it give error      ORA-20999: Failed to parse SQL query! ORA-06550: line 5, column 7: ORA-12704: character set mismatch  thank you

Comment: You haven't provided much info for me to work on. Can you update your question with enough info to reproduce this error ?

Comment: what is the information you need please ?

Comment: a table definition and insert statement with the english and arabic menu entry so I can do a select statement that returns that error ORA-209999

Comment: thank you so much its working now I will change the datatype from NVARCHAR2 to VARCHAR2 :)))